# Make sure user session data is aggregated correctly over multiple workers in apache beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Let's assume I have the following session data split over two workers:

```
+---------+-----------+--------+
| user_id | timestamp | worker |
+---------+-----------+--------+
|       1 |         2 |      1 |
|       1 |         1 |      1 |
|       1 |        21 |      1 |
|       1 |        23 |      2 |
|       1 |        24 |      2 |
+---------+-----------+--------+
```

I want to make sure that if I agreggate the data, I will get the following result:

```
+---------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
| user_id | session_start | session_end | element_count |
+---------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
|       1 |             1 |           2 |             2 |
|       1 |            21 |          24 |             3 |
+---------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
```

And not the following result:

```
+---------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
| user_id | session_start | session_end | element_count |
+---------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
|       1 |             1 |           2 |             2 |
|       1 |            21 |          21 |             1 |
|       1 |            23 |          24 |             2 |
+---------+---------------+-------------+---------------+
```

For example in [this](https://de.talend.com/blog/2016/06/01/how-to-aggregate-clickstream-data-with-apache-spark/) use case, I would have to partition the input by user id to have all the session data for a user before splitting it into the session windows.

My questions would be:

- Does Apache Beam automatically make sure that each worker has all the data?
- For example, does this code snippet make sure that all user sessions are 
  agreggated correctly, even if the data was split over multiple workers?

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.transforms.window import Session

(pcoll 
 | beam.WindowInto(Session(gap_size=10))
 | beam.GroupByKey())
```

- If so, how exactly does it guarantee this behaviour?
- How can I replicate this specific situation locally so I can test it?
- Were can I read more about this behaviour in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

> Does Apache Beam automatically make sure that each worker has all the data?
>   For example, does this code snippet make sure that all user sessions are agreggated correctly, even if the data was split over multiple workers?

The Apache Beam semantics does not depend on which data is processed by which worker. It is up to a particular Beam runner to guarantee that it executes the pipeline correctly. If some runner needs to gather all the data on one worker to do it - then that runner should do that; if the runner can guarantee correctness without doing that - even better.

> If so, how exactly does it guarantee this behaviour?

The exact implementation details of efficiently evaluating windowing and triggers are very complex. You can look at the java implementation in [ReduceFnRunner](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/core-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/core/ReduceFnRunner.java). But at a high level, you can think of it like this (this is just a mental model, not an exact implementation):

- The Window transform assigns each element into one or more windows based on its timestamp.
- The GroupByKey transform implicitly groups by both key and window, i.e. for every key/window pair it maintains a buffer of elements with this key and window.
- If the windowfn is "merging" (i.e. if the windows of different elements with the same key are not independent - like is the case with session windows), it recomputes the correct set of windows for all elements with this key, and remaps each element into the respective new windows. (`mergeWindows`)

> How can I replicate this specific situation locally so I can test it?

Use the direct runner that runs the pipeline in-memory locally, and provides a reference implementation of the Beam model.

Comment: Hi, for me there are still a few things left open. So if I want to combine user session data that was split by the runner over multiple workers, does for example the dataflow runner automatically guarantee that each sessions are generated independently from the split over the workers or do I have to parition the data, so that each worker gets only the data of a specific user?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you mean - it seems that you're assuming a particular implementation of sessions where partitioning would be important, but Beam implements it in a way that it's not. You will get correct results, and controlling partitioning is not only unnecessary but impossible ("partitions" in the Spark sense are not a part of the Beam programming model)